# Executing custom commands in Python project using Poetry

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, shell, python-poetry

In my project I have to run the `docker build` and `run` commands very frequently to build and run the container respectively. I'm using Poetry as the package manager. I'm looking for a counterpart of `npm run <custom-command>` to execute my command in project in Python using Poetry. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `scripts` section of the `pyproject.toml` file to define the custom command: https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#scripts

It would look something like:

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
mycommand = 'mypackage.mymodule:mycommand'
```

...where `'mypackage.mymodule:mycommand'` is the reference to the location of the function in the project python code where the command is implemented.

The command itself would be then be run using `poetry run <mycommand>`

Comment: the command is not a script inside the project. I wish to run `docker build -t <project_name>` using Poetry as explained in the question.

Answer (score 1):

**The solution was found when the project was initialized through poetry init, followed by writing code and installing dependencies. As a result, poetry install still throws an error about system arguments.**

The solution for my case was:

- Creating a project via `poetry new <your_project_name>`
- Going to the project folder via `cd`
- Writing code, specifically the structure that will be called in `[tool.poetry.scripts]`
- Install dependencies via poetry add
- Configuration via poetry install